# SQL Server : check if two tables exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Is this correct if I am trying to delete and create a new table when only and only both of these tables exist? The table B is coming from another SQL Server (same version of SQL Server 2012)

```
IF EXISTS ((SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableA]')
           AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
           INTERSECT
           (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AnotherServer].Database.dbo.TableB')
           AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE TableA

    SELECT *
    INTO TableA
    FROM [AnotherServer].Database.dbo.TableB
END
```

Comment: This question misses a lot. Can you please add the statement you are executing.

Comment: I tried a lot to add my code but it didnt let me. I just took screenshot of it. plz see attached.

Comment: it doesnt even let me add it in the comments. it says an error occurred during submission.

Comment: You can add code. Indent 4 spaces to make it format as code

Comment: tried that didnt work

Comment: I attached screenshot of the error.

Comment: Why do I keep getting negative comments? The website doesnt let me submit it. Its not my fault!

Comment: Yoiur second check for table existence is definitely wrong: `id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AnotherServer].Database.dbo.TableB` - you need to specify the table using `[server].[database].[schema].[tablename]` - the leading `[dbo].` is in the wrong place - remove that

Comment: @marc_s - Can you add it as a answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your second check for table existence is wrong:

```
(SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects 
 WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AnotherServer].Database.dbo.TableB')
```

The table should be referred to with a `[server].[database].[schema].[tablename]` qualified name - that leading `[dbo].` is out of place here, remove it and try again:

```
IF EXISTS (
            (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects 
             WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableA]')
             AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
            INTERSECT
            (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects 
             WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[AnotherServer].[Database].[dbo].[TableB]')
             AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
          )
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[TableA]

    SELECT *
    INTO [dbo].[TableA]
    FROM [AnotherServer].[Database].[dbo].[TableB]
END
```

**Update:** not entirely sure if the **remote table** would be listed in your local `dbo.sysobjects` catalog view..... can you try this check instead?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects 
           WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableA]')
           AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
   AND OBJECT_ID('[AnotherServer].[database].[dbo].[TableB]') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. Still same issue. Both Tables do exist but the If statement does not evaluate True. I dont understand why!

Comment: I mean I can do select * from dbo.tableA and select * from [AnotherServer].[Database].[dbo].[TableB] but it just doesnt go through the If statment. It things I guess one of them dont exist!

Comment: @user3314399: I don't know if the **remote** table would be present in your local server's `dbo.sysobjects` catalog view..... have you tried using ` IF OBJECT_ID('AnotherServer.database.dbo.TableB') IS NOT NULL` instead??

Comment: Yes I tried that too. no luck!

Comment: Tried the update too still returns not exists!

Answer (score 1):

You can check table existance with T-SQL function

```
OBJECT_ID("<table_name>")
```

So, in your case T-SQL code will be next

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableA') IS NOT NULL
    AND OBJECT_ID('AnotherServer.database.dbo.TableB') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE TableA

    INSERT INTO TableA
    SELECT * FROM AnotherServer.database.dbo.TableB
END
```

Additional information you can find in the MSDN page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190328(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Can you please look at the code I submitted. I did the same thing but it doesnt go through the code inside. Even though both tables do exist.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't go through the code'? Does the if statement evaluate true? Does tableA gets dropped?
Try to evaluate without the insert into, see if anything is selected

Comment: both TableA and TableB exist and have thousands of records. But, the if statment still doesnt evaluate True and does not drop the table A and insert into TableA.